# Why this model has not yet been built?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

my code similar like this:

```
class sub_sub_Block(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(sub_sub_Block, self).__init__(name='')
    if req==True:
        self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))

    if inf==True:
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))


  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.layer1(input_tensor)
    x = self.layer2(x)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)

class sub_Block(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(sub_Block, self).__init__(name='')
    if req==True:
        self.layer1 = sub_sub_Block(filters1, (1, 1))

    if inf==True:
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))


  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.layer1(input_tensor)
    x = self.layer2(x)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)


class Block(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(Block, self).__init__(name='')
    if req==True:
        self.layer1 = subBlock(filters1, (1, 1))

    if inf==True:
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))


  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.layer1(input_tensor)
    x = self.layer2(x)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)

block = Block(1, [1, 2, 3])
print(block(tf.zeros([1, 2, 3, 3])))
print(block.summary())
```

error messages is :

> ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify a
>   n `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

1. how to solve this problem?
2. does `tf.keras.Model` can't in other `tf.keras.Model` block?